# SPARQL regex FILTER with unicode characters

Tags: python, regex, sparql

I have following SPARQL query which I am using with virtuoso and pyodbc
I tried this :

```
queryUnicode = u"""
SELECT ?subject ?pred ?value
WHERE
{
    ?subject ?pred ?value.
    FILTER ( regex(str(?value), 'abcd\\u00e9.*$', "i") )
}"""
```

But if gave following error and no results back.

```
18:10:13 INFO: ERRS_0 22023 SR375 Invalid argument 2 to rdf_regex_impl. Must be narrow or wide string or an complete string RDF box
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Virtuoso bug handling unicode regex.